# How to properly handle excepetions when webscraping with python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping, exception

I'm doing some Webscraping and looking for the best way to handle exceptions (AttributeError and TypeError) when creating variables in a loop:

The code looks like:

```
# code to open webdriver, get url, search, open csv file...
while True:
    try:
        # code to get containers 
        for container in containers:
            title = container.find('div', {'class': ("mb-2 tipo")}).get_text()
            f.write(title + ';')
            rooms = container.find('div', {'class': ("quarto")}).get_text()
            f.write(rooms + ';')
            # and so on with lots of variables
```

I do have a lot of variables to capture and then write on a csv file. But when scraping, there will be times some of the variables will not exist.

I'm looking for the best pythonic way to handle exceptions when this occurs while registering that the variable was not found (and this could be as simple as writing "Nan" in csv file).

Should I write excepetions individually for each variable? or maybe use if/else statements? What's best way?

I would like something like this to be done:

```
    for container in containers:
        #var 1
        title = container.find('div', {'class': ("mb-2 tipo")}).get_text()
            f.write(title + ';')
        #var 2 
        try:
             rooms = container.find('div', {'class': ("quarto")}).get_text()
            f.write(rooms)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            f.write('Nan' + ';')
        #var 3 --> should I do the same as var 2 and so on?
```

My doubt is if this is the properly way to handle exceptions for each of a long list of variables

Comment: Will you want the program execution to end if one of the variables doesn't exist?

Comment: @AndrewBiddle no, I want the program to write "Nan" if the variable does not exit and procedes with its job. But I want to make this excepetion's handling for a lot of variables. My doubt is about the best and efficient way to do this

Comment: You really want optional chaining which is not a part of Python yet, which is why I do this stuff in the browser side

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like so that would handle the errors. This is assuming you are trying to find similar elements like the example you provided:

```
def write_element(file, container, class_name):
    try: 
        element = container.find('div', {'class': (class_name)}).get_text()
        file.write(element + ';')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        file.write('Nan' + ';')
```

And then call it:

```
for container in containers:
    write_element(f, container, 'title')
```